# The video tag is not working, it says file not found. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

I have looked at a bunch of different sources and they don't really tell me anything, so I would really appreciate any answers. I want a video to autoplay as the final product, but right now I just need it to show up. Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<h1>Hello there!</h1>

<video width="1000" height="1000" controls>
    <source src="hellothere.webm" type='video/webm'>
    Sorry, pumpkin
    
</video>
```

the video "hellothere.webm" is stored on my desktop in a folder. I get an error message saying that the file is not found, and I don't know what to do. This is on chrome. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your html file and video are in the same parent folder - i.e. both in that folder on your desktop. Otherwise, you can change the path of the video to point to that folder on your desktop. Hopefully the file should then be found.

As a side note, if you want the video to autoplay, add the autoplay attribute:

```
<video autoplay width="1000" height="1000" controls>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using an app called "Brackets", and I can't seem to find any file that matches my name when I search for it.

Comment: Ah wait no nevermind I found it! Thanks so much for your help :)